# Get notified when customer place an order in ruby on rails e commerce app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, actionmailer

I'm working on my first E-commerce web app to learn Ruby on Rails.
It's a steep learning curve :)

I need some guidance about how I can be notified by email when a customer place an order.

So far I've manage to build a `order notifier` so the customer is notified when it's order is placed and shipped as shown below.

*mailers/order_notifier.rb*

```
class OrderNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  default from: 'My Store Concept Store <orders@mystore.com>'

  def received(order)
    @order = order
    mail to: order.email, subject: 'My Store Concept Store'
  end

  def shipped(order)
    @order = order
    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped'
  end
end
```

this is working well but now I need to get notified my self via email, when user place an order at my store.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: And what the question? You can add `def notify_me(order)` with `mail to: 'me@mystore.com'` OR add `cc` or `bcc` to existing methods.

Comment: Thank you @PavelMikhailyuk it is basically that I was asking for.... I havn't tested it yet, but I'm sure it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a bcc options.

```
def received(order)
 @order = order
 mail(
 to: order.email,
 subject: 'My Store Concept Store'
 bcc:   %w[
     my@email_adress.com
     ]
 )
end
```

for example